# Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '' could not be parsed at index 0

Tags: java, parsing, localdate

I have a scanner to take 2 String and change them into LocalDate but it doesn't take the scanners in count and gave me this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '' could not be parsed at index 0
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(Unknown Source)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.time.LocalDate.parse(Unknown Source)     .....................location of my classes
```

The code :`

```
String date1 = sc1.nextLine();
String date2 = sc1.nextLine();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    LocalDate dateDebut = LocalDate.parse(date1,formatter);

    System.out.println(dateDebut);
    a1.setDateDeb(dateDebut);

    System.out.println(dateFin);
    a1.setDateFin(dateFin);
```

But when instead of the 2 scanners I put a String date ("12/12/2019") it works.

I don't know where it comes from.. I'm using Eclipse

Comment: I am unable to recreate this issue. What line is it exactly you are encountering the error?

Comment: is there a call to `nextInt` or so before calling `nextLine`?

Comment: yes I take 2 other parameters

Comment: so you are reading the end of that previous line...possible duplicate, hard to say without full code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/85421

Comment: you are right it was reading the previous line thank you

Comment: also check Sekhar's answer below (and the part `Text ''` of error exception indicates there is no text to parse)

Answer (score 1):

This error will occure while you enter the date in different format. You need to key in the date with dd/mm/yyyy format.

```
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Date1:");
    String date1 = sc1.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Date2:");
    String date2 = sc1.nextLine();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        LocalDate dateDebut = LocalDate.parse(date1,formatter);

        System.out.println(dateDebut);
      //  a1.setDateDeb(dateDebut);
        LocalDate dateFin = LocalDate.parse(date2,formatter);

        System.out.println(dateFin);
      //  a1.setDateFin(dateFin);
```

When we run the above code it will prompt to enter 2 dates.

Output:
Enter Date1:
05/05/2025
Enter Date2:
01/10/2022

**2025-05-05
2022-10-01**

Comment: That was because I had 2 scanner.nextLine() before.